# How can I make my container -places- act same way like container -content- in my code when I zoom it in?

Tags: html, css

`hi
I started to learn coding few days ago and there is something I cant figure out.
When I zoom in everything looks finde but the container places is zooming in the pictures too and a scrollbar appears. Id like to make that page without scrollbar to right side.
Can anybody tell me how can I fix it? thanks in advance

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="photostyle.css"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>photography</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <nav class="header__nav-ul">
            <a class="header__nav-li">
                <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">contact me</a>
            </a>
            <a class="header__nav-li">
                <a href="#" class="header__nav-link">guest book</a>
            </a>
        </nav>
        <h1>photography</h1>
        <h1>by <strong>DP</strong></h1>
        <hr width="30%" size="7" color="#c2e9fb">
    </header>
    <hr>
    <h2>categories</h2>
    <section class="content">
        <div class="animals"><h4>animals</h4></div>
        <div class="landscapes"><h4>landscapes</h4></div>
        <div class="nightshots"><h4>night shots</h4></div>
        <div class="otherpics"><h4>other pics</h4></div>
    </section>

    <hr>

    <h3>places worth a visit</h3>
<section class="places">

<div class="layout">
    <h5>Imperia -<br> Italy</h5>
            <div class="region">
            <img src="../images/italy.jpg" class="background-image1">
            <img src="../images/italy2.jpg" class="overlay-image1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="layout">
    <h5>Jelenia Gora -<br> Poland</h5>
            <div class="region">
            <img src="../images/jg2.jpg" class="background-image1">
            <img src="../images/jg.jpg" class="overlay-image1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="layout">
    <h5>Pfälzerwald -<br> Germany</h5>
            <div class="region">
            <img src="../images/pwald2.jpg" class="background-image1">
            <img src="../images/pwald.jpg" class="overlay-image1">
    </div>
</div>


 </section>
</body>
</html>

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 1em; /* 16px Standard */
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poiret One', sans-serif;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #f5f7fa 0%, #c3cfe2 100%);
}

.header {
    padding: 2rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-image: url(../images/photomainbackground.jpg);
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: #f5f7fa;
    text-shadow:  0.15rem 0.15rem 0.25rem #c3cfe2;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0rem 0.25rem 0.25rem #000000;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0rem 0.25rem 0.25rem #000000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #c3cfe2;
    padding: 2rem;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.438);
    color: #c3cfe2;
    width: 40%;
    height: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 999999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s linear;
    
}

h4:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    transition: 1s linear;
}

h5{
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #c3cfe2;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0rem 0.25rem 0.25rem #000000;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
}

.header__nav-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
    text-shadow: 0rem 0.15rem 0.35rem rgb(89, 97, 100);
    background-color: #f5f7fa;
    border-radius: 99999px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0rem 0.25rem 0.5rem #c3cfe2;
    
}

.header__nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    
}

.header__nav-ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

.header__nav-li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin: 2rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.animals {
    background-image: url(../images/animalscover.jpg);
   
}
.landscapes {
    background-image: url(../images/landscapecover.jpg);
    
}
.nightshots{
    background-image: url(../images/nightcover.jpg);
    
}
.otherpics {
    background-image: url(../images/restcover.jpg);
    
}
.animals, .landscapes, .nightshots, .otherpics {
    margin: 1rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50% 20% / 10% 40%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 0rem 0.15rem 1.35rem rgb(89, 97, 100);
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
        
        
}

.animals:hover, .landscapes:hover, .nightshots:hover, .otherpics:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

    
.places {
    background-image: url(../images/storiesbackground.jpg);
    padding: 0.2rem;
    padding: 10%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
   
           
}

.region {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../images/italy.jpg) ;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    
   
}
          

.background-image1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.overlay-image1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.6s;
    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.region:hover .overlay-image1 {
    opacity: 1;
}

.layout{
    margin: 0.2rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
}
```

I tried to use same CSS code in containers content and places `